# How to remove namespace from xml

Tags: xpath, xquery, osb

I have a XML in following format

```
<Body xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <TransactionAcknowledgement xmlns="">
    <TransactionId>HELLO </TransactionId>
    <UserId>MC</UserId>
    <SendingPartyType>SE</SendingPartyType>
  </TransactionAcknowledgement>
</Body>
```

I want to user XQuery or XPath expression for it.

Now I want to remove only

> xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

namespace from xml.

Is there any way to achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: XPath is a *query* language over XML document(a) and, as such, the evaluation of an XPath expression never modifies the source XML document(s) against which the expression is evaluated. What you need is an XML transformation. The best suited language for XML transformations is XSLT (XQuery can also be used, but is really clumsy because it lacks template matching). Would you be interested in an XSLT solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [functx:change-element-ns-deep](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_change-element-ns-deep.html):

```
let $xml := <Body xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <TransactionAcknowledgement xmlns="">
    <TransactionId>HELLO </TransactionId>
    <UserId>MC</UserId>
    <SendingPartyType>SE</SendingPartyType>
  </TransactionAcknowledgement>
</Body>

return functx:change-element-ns-deep($xml, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "")
```

But as said  Dimitre Novatchev this function doesn't change namespace of the source xml, it creates a new XML.